# How to plot an aligned text on severals lines / colomns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid, cowplot

I am creating a "page" via several lines and columns with aligned text (left/right/top/bottom). I would like to use the `grid.arrange()` function but I can't do it. I read in an old post that  the `grid_plot()` function does the job.

So my code is

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)

x <- unit(1:3/(3+1), "npc")
y <- unit(1:2/(2+1), "npc")
grid.grill(h=y, v=x, gp=gpar(col="grey"))

myPlot <- plot_grid(
  grid.text(label="Information:", x=x[1], y=y[2], just=c("left", "bottom"),  gp=gpar(fontface = "bold",  fontsize = 15, col = "black")),
  grid.text(label="Name:",        x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("right", "bottom"), gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "red")), 
  grid.text(label="John Doe ",    x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("left", "bottom"),  gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "blue"))
)
```

The display result is nice:
[image: Aligned plot]

But, if I save the plot in pdf file, the result is no-aligned

```
save_plot("myPlot.pdf", myPlot, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

The result is NOT as expected
[image: No aligned plot]

My question is: How I can align the text in pdf file ?

Comment: Did you try using the `align` argument of `plot_grid`?

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried all align parameters ("none", "h", "v" and "hv") witout success

Answer (score 1):

Your displayed result in the first case was **NOT** the result of `plot_grid`. What happened was that the `grid.text` function (unlike `textGrob`) draws the created text grob by default, so each of the three text grobs was drawn on *top* of one another in the same Grid viewport. From the viewport's perspective, what happened was equivalent to the following:

```
grid.grill(h=y, v=x, gp=gpar(col="grey"))
grid.text(label="Information:", x=x[1], y=y[2], just=c("left", "bottom"),  gp=gpar(fontface = "bold",  fontsize = 15, col = "black"))
grid.text(label="Name:",        x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("right", "bottom"), gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "red"))
grid.text(label="John Doe ",    x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("left", "bottom"),  gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "blue"))
```

Meanwhile, the `plot_grid` function took the created text grobs, arranged them according to the 2-row-2-column arrangement, and assigned the result to `myPlot`. In your original code, `myPlot` isn't actually drawn at all until the `save_plot` line. Had you drawn `myPlot` in R / RStudio's graphic device, it would have looked the same as what you got in pdf form. And what seems like mis-aligned texts at first glance are actually aligned exactly as intended--once we take into account that these are actually side-by-side plots, not overlaid ones:

```
myPlot
grid.grill(h = unit(1:5/6, "npc"), v = unit(1:7/8, "npc"), gp = gpar(col = "grey"))
grid.grill(h = unit(1/2, "npc"), v = unit(1/2, "npc"), gp = gpar(col = "black"))
```

[image]

If you want to overlay already-aligned text grobs on top of one another, you shouldn't be using `plot_grid` at all. The lower-level functions from the cowplot package would serve your purpose better:

```
# this is a matter of personal preference, but I generally find it less confusing to
# keep grob creation separate from complex cases of grob drawing / arranging.
gt1 <- grid.text(label="Information:", x=x[1], y=y[2], just=c("left", "bottom"),  
                 gp=gpar(fontface = "bold", fontsize = 15, col = "black"))
gt2 <- grid.text(label="Name:",        x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("right", "bottom"), 
                 gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "red"))
gt3 <- grid.text(label="John Doe ",    x=x[2], y=y[1], just=c("left", "bottom"),  
                 gp=gpar(fontface = "plain", fontsize = 13, col = "blue"))

# ggdraw() & draw_plot() fill up the entire plot by default, so the results are overlaid.
myPlot <- ggdraw(gt1) + draw_plot(gt2) + draw_plot(gt3)
myPlot # show in default graphics device to check alignment
save_plot("myPlot.pdf", myPlot) # save as pdf
```

[image]